# Protecting post routes NodeJS

Tags: node.js, api, express, security, routes

I am working on a nodeJS application. So far i've learned you can protect routes with JWT and i've implemented this. The problem is, I am not sure how to protect a route where the user is allowed to post to.

Let's take a register route for example, this route will be used for user registration. I want users to be able to post to this, BUT only from my application. I dont want anyone to just be able to connect to it via postman and post whatever. How do you protect these kind of routes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CORS middleware to allow only specific clients to access your server https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

Example:

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

var corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://example.com',
}

app.get('/products/:id', cors(corsOptions), function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for only example.com.'})
})

app.listen(80, function () {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80')
})
```