# How to secure and protect Nodejs api

Tags: node.js, api, react-native

I create some Nodejs api for my react native application. when user loggedin node send jwt as response and react native save jwt token in local storage. Now i want to know how can i secure my node js api so that only user who using my app can hit my api through app not external person. one solution i read that i send my token from react native app to node and verify that token. But one thing confusing me how about some person who copy any account token and send that token by pasting it, this way any person can use and hit my api externally. i want some guidance how can i secure my api.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Protecting post routes NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57722844/protecting-post-routes-nodejs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your API is exposed to the internet, you cannot prevent others from hitting it. However, you can implement IP whitelists, OAuth, session tokens, or some other means of authenticating requests.

If copying auth tokens is an issue, change them with every request, similar to [CSRF tokens](https://medium.com/@charithra/introduction-to-csrf-a329badfca49)

Comment: as you say "Change them with every request", but how  can i change my jwt token from client side. only way to change is to use jwt.sign() method and by using this method i have to use my secret key and if i use it in client side any one can access my secret key. I want to use this solution about change my token and add current time to that token but problem is i don't know exacctyle how can i change it with every time i request from client side i.e from my react native code

Comment: Change tokens on the server-side and send the new token to client along with the request response.

Comment: whats the difference any user can copy that token as i send it in response.
one of my friend suggest me that i can send current time from client side and check 1 minute duration in server side to allow access or not on every hit. but the problem is how can i send time from client as hashed string so that no one can get idea about that string.

Comment: Security through obscurity does not work http://users.softlab.ntua.gr/~taver/security/secur3.html